# LINQ distinct on class item?

Tags: linq, distinct, anonymous-types

Note this question is similar [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741299/linq-to-sql-distinct-with-anonymous-types) except I'm not working with linq-to-sql, so the "let" is not usable.

Basically I have a select of the type

```
... .Select(c => new SampleClass { Id = c.Location.Name, Name = c.Location.Name }).Distinct().ToList()
```

which used to work when I just had

```
... .Select(c => c.Location.Name).Distinct().ToList()
```

How would I make a distinct call on one of the items within the SampleClass?

Comment: "let" is usable in Linq to objects too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group items by the key, and then select what item from the group you want to use as value. I use `FirstOrDefault` as an example:

```
... .Select(c => new SampleClass { Id = c.Location.Name, Name = c.Location.Name })
    .GroupBy(c => c.Id)
    .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Correction: I would need to do a .GroupBy(c=> c.Id)

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you needed `c.Location.Name` because of the second code sample in your question. Anyway, I'll update accordingly

Comment: Why are `Id` and `Name` both set to `c.Location.Name`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need: http://sprokhorenko.blogspot.com/2009/11/convenient-distinct.html ?

This is an extension for IEnumerable that allows you to .Distinct() for any field (or even several ones using lambdas), which creates IEqualityComparer for you on the fly.

Comment: i almost voted you down for the external link ( i hate it to find a question with an answer and then not to be able to follow the links ), but since that link is actually Awesome, i didnt vote down.

Comment: OK, I'll keep that in mind for future. Thanks for the kind words, I'm glad my blog was useful for someone. Maybe it's time to continue writing ;-)

Comment: The approach described in the linked post is what I also prefer. I wonder why this extension method isn't included in the framework out-of-the-box, as it kinda jumps into your face once you have to deal with Distinct().

Comment: External link is dead