# distinct with LINQ

Tags: linq, distinct

```
 var sourceId =
            (from workstation in db.station
             join letter in db.letter on workstation.id equals letter.Site_Id
             where ThatDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
             select workstatio).ToList();
```

This produces a list which will print out repeats if more than one, how can I use .distinct?

Please advise, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ distinct on class item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930654/linq-distinct-on-class-item)

Comment: I'm assuming that Workstation : Letter is a one-to-many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var sourceId =
            (from workstation in db.station
             join letter in db.letter on workstation.id equals letter.Site_Id
             where ThatDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
             select workstation).Distinct().ToList();
```

Take a look at this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

Comment: that won't work as it will compare the object pointers and decide that they're all different objects

Comment: Then you will need to do something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [DistinctBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) method in [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/). Where you can pass a lambda expression as a parameter.

In your example it would look something similar to this:

```
var sourceId =
        (from workstation in db.station
         join letter in db.letter on workstation.id equals letter.Site_Id
         where ThatDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
         select workstatio).DistinctBy(ws => ws.Id).ToList();
```

You can also use DistinctBy with multiple properties:

```
var sourceId =
        (from workstation in db.station
         join letter in db.letter on workstation.id equals letter.Site_Id
         where ThatDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
         select workstatio).DistinctBy(ws => new {Id = ws.Id, OtherProperty = ws.OtherProperty}).ToList();
```

Btw, instead of reference-comparing, the equality of anonymous type instances is determined by comparing each one of their properties.

I have recently found an interesting discussion around this topic where Anders Hejlsberg himself suggests the solution to this problem. You can read it [here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/6834054e-e1c1-49db-970c-370a9012c675)