# Using a foreach loop on a List of two types?

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I know I can use a `foreach` loop as follows:

```
List<int> handles = GetHandles();

foreach (int handle in handles)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Can I do the same for a `SortedList` as follows?

```
SortedList<string, int> namesAndHandles;
```

EDIT: Sorry, made a typo. It should be a `SortedList`. Essentially I want to convert this to an `IDictionary` and access the handles based off a name

Comment: There is no `List<T1, T2>` in .NET. Is it your custom class?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: No; that what he's asking for.

Comment: what about Dictionary<K,V> ?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek sorry I made a typo. I meant `SortedList`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3319086/425003

Comment: Don't think so, it doesn't implement IEnumerable<SomeWrapperType<T1,T2>>, it only implements IEnumerable (non-generic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as `List<string, int>` - there's no `List<,>` type with two type parameters. If you've got a collection of name/handle pairs, you should either use `List<Tuple<string, int>>` or create your own `NameAndHandle` class. Either will work fine with `foreach`.

(You *could* create your own `List<TFirst, TSecond>` class if you really wanted, but I'd really advise against it.)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the `foreach` loop will work correctly on `List<Tuple<string, int>>`.

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry I meant `SortedList` I'll look into using Tuple

Comment: @ryrich: `SortedList` is really a map - it's unfortunately named, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I have a `List<string>` and `List<int>`, is it possible to populate a `List<Tuple<string, int>>` based off these lists?

Answer (score 0):

I bet List<KeyValuePair<string,int>> would do what you are looking for.  You could iterate the collection and the .Key property holds the string and .Value holds the int

Comment: I wouldn't do this unless they really *are* key/value pairs. I would avoid using `KeyValuePair` just as "a type with two type parameters to hold two values".