# Create Dictionary with LINQ and avoid "item with the same key has already been added" error

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find a key in a dictionary and **replace** the value if it is found or add the key/value if it is not.

Code:

```
public class MyObject
{

    public string UniqueKey { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }

}
```

LINQ Solution (throws `An item with the same key has already been added.`):

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> objectDict = csvEntries.ToDictionary(csvEntry => csvEntry.ToMyObject().UniqueKey, csvEntry => csvEntry.ToMyObject());
```

ForEach solution (works):

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> objectDict = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();
foreach (CSVEntry csvEntry in csvEntries)
{

    MyObject obj = csvEntry.ToMyObject();

    if (objectDict.ContainsKey(obj.UniqueKey))
    {
        objectDict[obj.UniqueKey] = obj;
    }
    else {
        objectDict.Add(obj.UniqueKey, obj);
    }

}
```

I really liked the LINQ solution but as it stands, it throws the above error. Is there any nice way of avoiding the error and using LINQ?

Comment: Use `ToLookup` instead of `ToDictionary`

Comment: I would create a class `MyObjectComparer` that implements `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>` and use the following line: `Dictionary<string, MyObject> objectDict = csvEntries.Select(entry => entry.ToMyObject()).Distinct(new MyObjectComparer()).ToDictionary(csvEntry => csvEntry.UniqueKey, csvEntry => csvEntry);`

Comment: The indexer adds the element if it exists so you can just remove the `ContainsKey` check and always use `objectDict[obj.UniqueKey] = obj`.

Comment: Your dictionary is a bit unusual. Every entry contains two copies of UniqueKey, one in the key and one in the object.

Comment: For an efficient solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22508992.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to create unique keys:

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> objectDict = csvEntries
    .Select(csvEntry => csvEntry.ToMyObject())
    .GroupBy(x => x.UniqueKey)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.First());
```

However, instead of `grp.First()` you could create a collection with `ToList` or `ToArray`. On that way you don't take an arbitary object in case of duplicate keys. Or add your priority-logic in an `OrderBy` before `First`: `grp => grp.OrderBy(x => Field1).ThenBy(x => x.Field2).First()`

Another option is to use a `Lookup<TKey, TValue>` which allows duplicate keys and even non-existing keys, you get an empty sequence in that case.

```
var uniqueKeyLookup = csvEntries
    .Select(csvEntry => csvEntry.ToMyObject())
    .ToLookup(x => x.UniqueKey);
IEnumerable<MyObject> objectsFor1234 = uniqueKeyLookup["1234"]; // empty if it doesn't exist
```

Comment: The first solution worked for me, however `ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.First());` needs to be `ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Last());` because I want the key's value to be *replaced* by a later entry.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter , I am facing similar issue with this statement-                                                               
If TempDT IsNot Nothing Then m_ConcurrentScriptDictionary = TempDT.AsEnumerable.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.SafeField(fldClusterId, NULL_ID_VALUE), Function(y) y.SafeField(fldParamValue11, NULL_ID_VALUE))             , Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Building on Tim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31520060/284240), here's an extension method you can use so you don't need to duplicate the implementation throughout your project:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionaryWithDupSelector<TKey, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TValue> enumerable,
        Func<TValue, TKey> groupBy, Func<IEnumerable<TValue>, TValue> selector = null) {

        if (selector == null)
            selector = new Func<IEnumerable<TValue>, TValue>(grp => grp.First());

        return enumerable
            .GroupBy(e => groupBy(e))
            .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => selector(grp));
    }
}
```

By default it will choose the first element when there are duplicates, but I have provided an optional parameter where you can specify an alternate selector. Example call to the extension method:

```
var objList = new List<string[]> {
    new string[2] {"1", "first"},
    new string[2] {"1", "last"},
    new string[2] {"2", "you"},
};
var asDict = objList.ToDictionary(
    arr => arr[0],
    grp => grp.Last()
);
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue with this statement-                                                               
If TempDT IsNot Nothing Then m_ConcurrentScriptDictionary = TempDT.AsEnumerable.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.SafeField(fldClusterId, NULL_ID_VALUE), Function(y) y.SafeField(fldParamValue11, NULL_ID_VALUE))