# Dictionary from nested list

Tags: c#

I have list of object and its relation.

```
public class Rack
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Now I am trying to make dictionary List of racks but with the key as Product Name and values as Racks ( product belonging to which all racks)

```cs
var allRacks = GetAllRacks(); // List of racks 
var dict = allRacks
                .SelectMany(rack => 
                    rack.Product.Select(prod => new 
                    { 
                        key = prod.Name, 
                        value = prod.Name, 
                    })
                ).ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```

But I get error as key are already added.

So how to select distinct key here or any other way to do that?

```
Rack   Product 
R1     P1,P2,P3 
R2     P3,P4 
R3     P2,P4

And output as dictionary 

P1     R1
P2     R1,R3
P3     R1
P4     R2,R3
```

Comment: can you post more relevant code, what type is allRacks here?

Comment: Group by Rack.Name. Also, use meaningful variable names (i.e. `rack` instead of `f`, `product` instead of `g`).  Also, a [mre] would be good here.

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319016/convert-list-to-dictionary-using-linq-and-not-worrying-about-duplicates

Comment: *But I get error as key are already added* Yes, this is unavoidable if two of your racks end up mapping to the same product name, because a dictionary will only allow the product name to appear once. Perhaps you should use a [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-7.0) instead of a dictionary. A `Lookup` can contain several racks for a single product name.

Comment: Result should be a `Dictionary<string, List<Rack>>`?

Comment: I am trying to create product as key which will be in many rack.

Comment: @Ralf , yes. string ( product Name) and value as List<Rack>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to access your values with multiple results per key you should actually be using ToLookup `(ILookup<string, List<Rack>>)` here

```cs
var allRacks = GetAllRacks();
var dict = allRacks.SelectMany(f => f.Product.Select(g => new { key = g.Name, value = f.Name }))
                   .ToLookup(f => f.key, f => f.value);
```

Or if you are for some reason insist on `Dictionary<string, List<Rack>>` works like this:

```cs
var dict = allRacks
   .SelectMany(rack => rack.Products.Select(product => (product, rack)))
   .GroupBy(d => d.product.Name, (s, tuples) => (productName: s, racks : tuples.Select(d => d.rack).ToList()))
   .ToDictionary(d => d.productName, d=> d.racks);
```

Comment: Presumably `value = f.Name` should be just `value = f` as he wanted to find a rack not just the name of the rack.

Comment: Thanks @Dbl. All other solution worked provided by others but your first options is simple and worked as expected (lookup).

Answer (score 1):

You can't have duplicated keys within `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, so you should `GroupBy` all records by product Name
and then turn grouping into the dictionary:

```
var dict = GetAllRacks()
  .SelectMany(rack => rack
     .Products
     .Select(product => (product : product.Name, rack : rack)))
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.product, pair => pair.rack)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have duplicate names.  Try following :

```cs
List<Rack> allRacks = GetAllRacks(); 
Dictionary<string, List<Rack>>  dict = 
        allRacks.SelectMany(f => f.Products.Select(g => new 
                            { 
                                key = g.Name, 
                                rack = f,
                            })
                ).GroupBy(x => x.key, y => y.rack)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
```