# AND Operator cannot work with bool and string

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ2SQL statement where I am using two criteria:

```
var query1 = from r in dt.Test
                                where r.ID == 92 
                                && r.Status = '"I"
                                select r.ID && r.Status = "I"
```

But its giving me an err that AND (&&) operator cannot work with string and bool. Whats the turnaround for this?

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: I do not understand the question "Whats the turnaround for this?". By "turnaround" do you mean "explanation"?

Comment: Is the extra `'` infront of `"I"` a typo?

Comment: `=` (assignment) != `==` (equality)

Comment: Are you mixing up equality and assignment with your equals operator?

Comment: Thanks guys, it was a typo on my side. Appreciate all your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing your `=` signs with `==`

```
var query1 = from r in dt.Test
                            where r.ID == 92 
                            && r.Status == "I"
                            select r.ID && r.Status == "I"
```

Remember that `=` in C# is the assignment operator, and `==` is the equality operator. As someone who regularly flips between C# and VB.NET, I often come unstuck here!

Comment: I get flamed but "I" = r.Status would have caught this as a compile error

Comment: @kim9971 - Happy to help! Don't forget to choose an answer to your question by clicking the "tick" on the left :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a single equals sign `r.Status = '"I"`, should be `r.Status == '"I"`

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo from my side.

Answer (score 1):

You mean `==` in place of `=`; the assignment expression (as opposed to the equality operator) is confusing things; instead of returning a bool, the result of `r.Status = "I"` is a string... `"I"`

```
var query1 = from r in dt.Test
             where r.ID == 92 && r.Status == "I"
             select r.ID;
```

(not quite sure what to make of the last part of your `select`, so I omitted it)

Answer (score 1):

1. `=` is used for assignment and `==` is used for equality.
2. I am not sure what result you're expecting, but `select r.ID && r.Status == "I"` (even with 2 equal signs) is not valid in any case.

Depending on what you want to select, if the result is the amount of the rows qualifying for your search consider using [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737922#countcond).
If you want to select these two values, use a POCO class or an [anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543482/linq-select-distinct-with-anonymous-types):

```
var query1 = from r in dt.Test
             where r.ID == 92 && r.Status == "I"
             select new { ID = r.ID, Status = r.Status };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query1 = from r in dt.Test
             where r.ID == 92 && r.Status == "I"
             select r.ID && r.Status == "I";
```