# LINQ to SQL omit field from results while still including it in the where clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Basically I'm trying to do this in LINQ to SQL;

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM table WHERE z=35
```

I have tried this, (c# code)

```
(from record in db.table
select new table {
    a = record.a,
    b = record.b,
    c = record.c
}).Where(record => record.z.Equals(35)).Distinct();
```

But when I remove column z from the table object in that fashion I get the following exception;

> Binding error: Member 'table.z' not found in projection.

I can't return field z because it will render my distinct useless. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**Edit:**

This is a more comprehensive example that includes the use of PredicateBuilder,

```
var clause = PredicateBuilder.False<User>();
clause = clause.Or(user => user.z.Equals(35));
foreach (int i in IntegerList) {
    int tmp = i;
    clause = clause.Or(user => user.a.Equals(tmp));
}

var results = (from u in db.Users
               select new User {
                   a = user.a,
                   b = user.b,
                   c = user.c
               }).Where(clause).Distinct();
```

**Edit2:**

Many thanks to everyone for the comments and answers, this is the solution I ended up with,

```
var clause = PredicateBuilder.False<User>();
clause = clause.Or(user => user.z.Equals(35));
foreach (int i in IntegerList) {
    int tmp = i;
    clause = clause.Or(user => user.a.Equals(tmp));
}

var results = (from u in db.Users
               select u)
               .Where(clause)
               .Select(u => new User {
                   a = user.a,
                   b = user.b,
                   c = user.c
               }).Distinct();
```

The ordering of the Where followed by the Select is vital.

Comment: May I humbly suggest that you rename your data types and properties a bit? The fact that you create a new *record* by writing `new table { … }` seems quite confusing and non-intuitive, especially because there appears to be a property `db.table` that is a collection of `table`-like objects...

Comment: I was just trying to change references to be more generic for the example. Can those that downvoted please provide an explanation so that I don't make the same question-asking mistake in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

problem is there because you where clause is outside linq query and you are applying the where clause on the new anonymous datatype thats y it causing error

Suggest you to change you query like

```
(from record in db.table
where record.z == 35
select new table {
    a = record.a,
    b = record.b,
    c = record.c
}).Distinct();
```

Comment: I see. Is it possible to do this using `PredicateBuilder`? I am building up a chain of clauses that is only known at runtime.

Comment: @Rob2211 - well you can check the post by me : http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/04/dynamic-query-with-linq.html might help you

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting this as the answer since it explains the problem with the originally posted code.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just put the WHERE clause in the LINQ?

```
(from record in db.table
where record.z == 35
select new table {
    a = record.a,
    b = record.b,
    c = record.c
}).Distinct();
```

Alternatively, if you absolutely had to have it the way you wrote it, use .Select

.Select(r => new { a = r.a, b=r.b, c=r.c }).Distinct();

As shown here [LINQ Select Distinct with Anonymous Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543482/linq-select-distinct-with-anonymous-types), this method will work since it compares all public properties of anonymous types.

Hopefully this helps, unfortunately I have not much experience with LINQ so my answer is limited in expertise.

Comment: Thanks Daryl, this answer helped me with my eventual solution. I didn't realise I could do `(from foo in bar select a).Where().Select()`