# Get a list of unrepeated possible values of a field using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List of items of type DataItem (`List<DataItem>`):

```
public class DataItem
{
    public DataItem() { }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

There may be many items with the same string in `Category` field.

How can I extract a list of different possible categories using Linq?

What I want as a result is a `List<string>` which has all the values found for `Category` property, but doesn't have repeated values.

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719928/how-to-use-linq-distinct-with-multiple-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) method:

```
var result = itemsList.Select(n => n.Category).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`yourList.Select(item => item.Category).Distinct().ToList();`