# Remove duplicate from the following list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class Items with properties (Id, Name, DrugCode1, DrugCode2).

The List of Items is populated with duplicated items.

For eg.:

```
------------------------------------------
Id        Name     DrugCode1  DrugCode2
------------------------------------------
1         Item1       2         3
2         Item2       3         2
3         Item3       4         3
1         Item1       3         2
3         Item3       3         4
```

If the DurgCode1 and DrugCode2 are reversed then we consider the items to be duplicates

eg:

```
1         Item1       2         3
1         Item1       3         2
```

The above 2 itmes are considered duplicate since the DrugCode1 and DrugCode2 are reversed.
We just need to fetch only one item.

How to remove the duplicates in the list using linq?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use LINQ Distinct() with multiple fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719928/how-to-use-linq-distinct-with-multiple-fields)

Comment: What about `Item3`? It also appears two times, with codes `4,3` and `3,4`...

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not tagged the linq-provider i presume `Linq-To-Objects`. You could use an anonymous type in the same order for `GroupBy`:

```
IEnumerable<Item> distinctItems = items
  .GroupBy(i => new { Min=Math.Min(i.DrugCode1, i.DrugCode2),Max=Math.Max(i.DrugCode1, i.DrugCode2) })
  .Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 3):

LINQ Distinct admits a `IEqualityComparer<T>` as parameter. Choosing this way, you may implement your own IEqualityComparer like this:

```
class ItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{

    public bool Equals(Item i1, Item i2) 
    {
        if (i1.ID == i2.ID && i1.Name == i2.Name && 
           (i1.DrugCode1 == i2.DrugCode1 || i1.DrugCode1 == i2.DrugCode2 ||    
            i1.DrugCode2 == i2.DrugCode1 ))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int  GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        int hash = 13;
        int min = Math.Min(obj.DrugCode1, obj.DrugCode2);
        int max = Math.Max(obj.DrugCode1, obj.DrugCode2);
        hash = (hash * 7) + min;
        hash = (hash * 7) + max;
        return hash;
    }  
}
```

Now you can use it:

```
var cleanList = listOfItems.Distinct(new ItemEqualityComparer());
```

It's a little bit longer than a Lambda Expression but it's clean, simple and re-usable.

Please, check the class name (Items should be Item).

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.Distinct` has an overload that takes a custom `IEqualityComparer` parameter. Pass in a function that treats two items as equal if their drug codes match in either order.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an `IEqaulityComparer` and then use it with `Distinct`

```
class ItemEuqalityComprer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.DrugCode1 == y.DrugCode2
               && x.DrugCode2 == y.DrugCode1;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        return obj.Id == null ? 0 : obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The usage with `Distinct`:

```
        var item1 = new Item {DrugCode1 = "2", DrugCode2 = "3"};
        var item2 = new Item {DrugCode1 = "3", DrugCode2 = "2"};
        var item3 = new Item { DrugCode1 = "3", DrugCode2 = "4" };
        var items = new[] {item1, item2, item3};

        var distincts = items.Distinct(new ItemEuqalityComprer());
```