# how do I write LINQ query to retrieve distinct records based on only specific properties?

Tags: c#, linq

I've an array of objects `DataTestplans` from which I try to retrieve records for a particular `DataID` and `ProductID` using the LINQ query shown, my current query has `Distinct()` which distiguishes on all 5 mentioned properties,how do I retrieve distinct records based on properties `DataID`,`TestPlanName`,`TCIndexList` and `ProductID`?

DataTestplans:-

```
[
    {
    "DataTestPlanID": 0,
    "DataID": 19148,
    "TestPlanName": "string",
    "TCIndexList": "string",
    "ProductID": 2033915
  },
    {
    "DataTestPlanID": 0,
    "DataID": 19148,
    "TestPlanName": "string",
    "TCIndexList": "string",
    "ProductID": 2033915
  },
      {
    "DataTestPlanID": 0,
    "DataID": 19149,
    "TestPlanName": "string",
    "TCIndexList": "string",
    "ProductID": -2642
  }

]
```

LINQ

```
            DataTestPlans_DataID_ProductID = DataTestPlans.Where(c => c.DataID == DataID_ProductID_Record.DataID && c.ProductID == DataID_ProductID_Record.ProductID).Distinct();
```

Comment: You can write a class that implements `IComparer` and pass an instance of that to `Distinct()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use LINQ Distinct() with multiple fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719928/how-to-use-linq-distinct-with-multiple-fields)

Comment: Klinger - what you pointed doesnt have an accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do like this..

```
DataTestPlans.Where(c => c.DataID == YourInput && c.ProductID == YourInput)
             .GroupBy(x => new {x.DataID,x.TestPlanName,x.TCIndexList,x.ProductID})
             .Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: Yes, basically that.  Note that in this example, the value of the field that wasn't grouped on is essentially random.  If you care about that value, you'll have to find some way of aggregating it from the group.   Also, `FirstOrDefault()` shouldn't be necessary, since each group will have at least one member or it won't be a group.  (So it could just be `First()`.)

Comment: I like your solution, but would consider replacing `.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());` with `.SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))`. It's a clearer approach and prevents spurious default values should you do a filter after the `GroupBy`.

Comment: @ChrisBerger - There is an issue with using `.First()` after a `.GroupBy(...)` if you refactor and put a `.Select(x => x.Where(...))` between them as this would produce wrong values.

Comment: can you explain the difference between `FirstOrDefault()` and `First()`.Also between `SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))` and `.Select(x => x.First());`  in layman terms...what is the advantage of on over the other

Comment: @user3508811 : FirstOrDefault() returns default value of data type in the context if the sequence is emtpy. For example, `FirstOrDefault()` on empty list of int returns `0`. `First()` fails with an exception if sequence is emtpy.

Comment: got it,any reason why you didnt take `x.Take(1)` part of suggestion from Enigmativity

Comment: @user3508811 : Select many flattens the list. For example,` List<List<int>>` will be converted to `List<int>`

Comment: @user3508811: while he got a point there, but it is irrelevant in your case. Both have same impact in your case. So, i just ignore dit.

Comment: `.SelectMany(x => x.First());` is throwing an error `The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany<Tsource,Result'(IEnumberable<TSource>,Func<TSource,IEnumerable<TResult>>) cannot be infterred from usage,Try specifying the type arguments explicity`

Comment: Not ideal - a GroupBy forces enumeration of the whole source before continuing, which is not scalable for large data sets. The answer @Neolisk gives is better recommended because it preserves lazy enumeration. Additionally, using GroupBy only to discard all but the first member of a group means wasted computation, while a custom extension method can (and does) evaluate only what is needed.

Comment: @user3508811 : SelectMany is not needed. check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do, both highlighted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda), no need for IComparer. Here is a quick example you can play with (I did not use your actual object, because it's easier to explain this way):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var persons = Setup();

        //option 1, can stream, option suggested by Jon Skeet
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/1300116/897326
        var result1 = persons.
            DistinctBy(m => new {m.FirstName, m.LastName});

        //option 2, cannot stream, but does reference to DistinctBy
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158364/897326
        var result2 = persons.
            GroupBy(m => new { m.FirstName, m.LastName }).
            Select(group => group.First());
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    private static List<Person> Setup()
    {
        var p1 = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Doe",
            Address = "USA"
        };

        var p2 = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Doe",
            Address = "Canada"
        };

        var p3 = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "Jane",
            LastName = "Doe",
            Address = "Australia"
        };

        var persons = new List<Person>();
        persons.Add(p1);
        persons.Add(p2);
        persons.Add(p3);

        return persons;
    }
}

public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Darkknight answers works and is much simpler which is what I was looking for

Comment: @user3508811: Darkknight provided option #2. It does not require any external dependencies but is a bit cryptic. It's not obvious that it's doing Distinct for a casual programmer who doesn't know LINQ. There is also option #1 suggested by Jon Skeet, which supports streaming. Depending on how large you data is, this may be useful. The syntax is cleaner also.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `GroupBy()`, which will create an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` which you can iterate over.  You can access records either with group.First() or by some sort of aggregate function over the group.

Comment: Would you provide a sample on what exactly you mean,that would really help

Comment: See DarkKnight's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple chained wheres . Make sure you it is IQueryable if you are making db call. An example is below

```
List<SomeClass> c = new List<SomeClass>();
 var result = c.Where(x => x.ID == 4).Distinct().Where(y => y.Name == "foo").Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `IEqualityComparer` and use that instead default in `Distinct()` method. If you example implement `DataTestPlansComparer` you can use like in following example:

```
DataTestPlans_DataID_ProductID = DataTestPlans.Where(c => c.DataID == DataID_ProductID_Record.DataID && c.ProductID == DataID_ProductID_Record.ProductID).Distinct(new DataTestPlansComparer());
```

Note, your custom comparer should be passed as parameter to `Distinct()` method.

In your case can be:

```
        public class DataTestPlanComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataTestPlan>
        {
            public bool Equals(DataTestPlan x, DataTestPlan y)
            {

                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                    return false;

                return x.DataID == y.DataID && x.ProductID == y.ProductID;
            }


            public int GetHashCode(DataTestPlan dataTestPlan)
            {
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(dataTestPlan, null)) return 0;

                int hashDataTestPlanDataID = dataTestPlan.DataID == null ? 0 : dataTestPlan.DataID.GetHashCode();

                int hashDataTestPlanProductID = dataTestPlan.ProductID.GetHashCode();

                return hashDataTestPlanDataID ^ hashDataTestPlanProductID;
            }
        }
```

Please follow [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx) guide to implement IEqualityComparer.