# How to distinct a duplicate row in EF Core 6 with method syntax?

Tags: linq, count, distinct, ef-core-6.0, linq-method-syntax

I want to query my database where I am searching a contract id by grouping them with `LcNoListId`. It is possible to contains duplicate value in `LcNoListId` column against a contract id. At this point I need to distinct all the duplicate `LcNoListId` and need to return without duplicate record.

I tried the below function for returning rows without duplicate value in `LcNoListId` column. But the `Distinct()` function is not working.

```
[HttpGet("contract-no/{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<BTBPending> objBTBPendingList = _unitOfWork.BTBPending.GetAll(includeProperties: "ProformaInvoice,ContractList,SupplierList,CountryList,ItemList,BuyerList,StyleList,TradeTermList,ErpRemarksList,StatusList,LcNoList,UdAmendList");
            
        var query = objBTBPendingList
                .Where(x => x.ContractListId == id && x.UdAmendList == null)
                .GroupBy(c => c.LcNoListId)
                .Where(grp => grp.Distinct().Count() > 1);

        // var que = Company.Distinct();
        return Ok(query);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"Something went wrong in the {nameof(Get)}");
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error, Please Try Again Leter!");
   }
}
```

This function returns all the rows which contain duplicate value in the `LcNoListId` column. But I don't need any duplicate values in `LcNoListId` column.

It is clearly shown that this `Distinct()` function is not working in this context. Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10720079/7687666) first, if it not works, please let me know.

Comment: ASP.NET is a web app framework, not a database library or ORM. Your code has a critical bug too - it's loading the entire table in memory, then trying to filter the loaded objects using LINQ, without any benefit of indexes. That `GetAll` should never be used in queries. EF Core doesn't need repositories (a DbContext is already a multi-entity UoW and repository)

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. `DISTINCT()` works fine here. It's applied to in-memory objects though, not rows. Inside an object group, the rows are most likely distinct. If you want to return only a single object per `LcNoListId` you can use [DistinctBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-7.0) instead of `GroupBy`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```cs
var query = objBTBPendingList
    .Where(x => x.ContractListId == id && x.UdAmendList == null)
    .GroupBy(c => c.LcNoListId)
    .Select(grp => grp.First());
```

But looks like you have stuck with ineffective repository pattern realization. With pure EF Core it is possible to make more performant query and do not retrieve duplicates and not wanted records from database.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This method is working fine. But instead of using First () I solved this by using Take (1). And thanks a lot again

Comment: My mistake, fixed last operator.