# Distinct in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

How I can make this Distinct work:

```
   var blockIdMap = (from panelEntry in panelEntries
                          select new {panelEntry.BlockNo, panelEntry.BlockID})
                          .Distinct()
                          .ToDictionary(mc => mc.BlockNo , mc => mc.BlockID);
```

I need to have only unique entries of BlockNo with it's BlockId because I enter them to Dictionary and BlockNo should be unique.
I want just to take the first one.

Comment: You could always `GroupBy` `BlockNo` and then select `First` `BlockID`. The only way to change `Distinct` is with an `IEqualityComparer<T>` or to use a class that implements `IEquatable<T>` and overrides `GetHashCode`. You cannot do the former with anonymous types, and they have their own implementation for the latter that is locked.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - [The compiler overrides GetHashCode and Equals for anonymous types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/543591/219661)

Comment: @Jamiec I know, I amended my comment to state that you cannot change the implementation as my first draft was inaccurate. The default implementation will take all properties into account, not just the `BlockNo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var blockIdMap = panelEntries.GroupBy(pe => pe.BlockNo)
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.First())
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case your linq query doesn't work beacuse [`.Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb348436.aspx) method equals `panelEntry.BlockNo` and `panelEntry.BlockID` and not only `panelEntry.BlockNo`. So a solution could be use [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/downloads/detail?name=morelinq-1.0-beta.zip) and the method `.DistinctBy()`:

```
var blockIdMap = (from panelEntry in panelEntries
                 select new {panelEntry.BlockNo, panelEntry.BlockID})
                 .DistinctBy(mc => mc.BlockNo)
                 .ToDictionary(mc => mc.BlockNo , mc => mc.BlockID);
```