# How do I get a distinct list of list types

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code (copy and paste it into linqpad if you like)

```
var messageUsers = new [] { 
    new { MsgId = 2, UserId = 7 },
    new { MsgId = 2, UserId = 8 },
    new { MsgId = 3, UserId = 7 },
    new { MsgId = 3, UserId = 8 },
    new { MsgId = 1, UserId = 7 },
    new { MsgId = 1, UserId = 8 },
    new { MsgId = 1, UserId = 9 }};

messageUsers
    .GroupBy (x => x.MsgId, x => x.UserId)
    .Select (x => x.Select (y => y))
    .Distinct()
    .Dump();
```

The results I get back are {7,8}, {7,8}, {7,8,9}

What I want is {7,8}, {7,8,9}.

Basically I want to remove the duplicate lists.
I haven't tried this but I think I could probably achieve by creating a comparer and passing it into the Distinct method.  However I would like to eventually use this in a Linq to Entities query without bringing thousands of rows back to the client so that isn't a good option.

For extra clarification...I need to return a List> where the contents of each inner list is distinct in comparison to any of the other inner list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `.Distinct()` determines what's distinct based on the `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` implementation of the underlying objects. In this case, the underlying object is something that implements `IEnumerable<>`, but which uses the default `object` implementation for those methods--which is based purely on whether the objects occupy the same space in memory.  So as far as it can tell, the sequences are not distinct, even though they have the same values in them.

How about this?

```
messageUsers
    .GroupBy (x => x.MsgId, x => x.UserId)
    .GroupBy(x => string.Join(",", x))
    .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
    .Dump();
```

The idea is to group by a key that represents the combined value of the elements in your list. You could also pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<>` to the `Distinct` method in your original code, but that seems like a fair bit of effort for something so trivial.

It's worth noting that this won't work very well if you're using LINQ to Entities or something like that.

#### Update

To make it a `List<List<int>>`, you'll need a few `.ToList()`s thrown in there:

```
messageUsers
    .GroupBy (x => x.MsgId, x => x.UserId)
    .GroupBy(x => string.Join(",", x))
    .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault().ToList())
    .ToList()
    .Dump();
```

But I'm frankly not sure why that matters to you.

Comment: Perfect, I was thinking flattening as a string might be the answer but couldn't work it out...nice one, thanks :-)

Comment: Anonymous types properly override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`...  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543482/linq-select-distinct-with-anonymous-types)

Comment: I think the [first] Select does have a use, it removes the IGrouping type from the result.

Comment: @TwistedInferno Which it doesn't need to do, since `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable`, and thus will work just fine in `Join`.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Yes, but IEnumerables typically don't. He's trying to get distinct lists of values, not distinct combos of values.

Comment: But I want the result to be IEnumerable<List<int>> not IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,int>>, could do .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault().Select (y => y)) as the last select

Comment: @TwistedInferno: Neither code snippet will give you a `List<List<int>>`--for that you would need to throw a few `.ToList()` calls in there.

Comment: basically I don't need the key in my result

Comment: @striplingwarrior, ah yes, quite right.  I had missed that.

Comment: Hmmm, after waking up this morning and trying this in Linq to Entities I realise that String.Join is not recognised by Linq to Entities and the query fails as a result.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just edited with alternatives, I'll leave it open just in case anybody can come up with a linq to EF only solution

Comment: @TwistedInferno: I think people rejected your edit because it essentially changes the nature of the answer. You're welcome to create your own answer with that additional information, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative answer:

```
messageUsers
    .GroupBy (x => x.MsgId, y=>y.UserId)
    .Select (x => new HashSet<int>(x))
    .Distinct(HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer())
    .Dump();
```

Consider the following input:

```
var messageUsers = new [] { 
    new { MsgId = 2, UserId = 7 },
    new { MsgId = 2, UserId = 8 },
    new { MsgId = 3, UserId = 8 },
    new { MsgId = 3, UserId = 7 },
    new { MsgId = 1, UserId = 7 },
    new { MsgId = 1, UserId = 8 },
    new { MsgId = 1, UserId = 9 }};
```

What result do you want?

{7,8}, {7,8,9} or {7,8}, {8,7}, {7,8,9}.

Comment: +1. I didn't know about HashSet.CreateSetComparer(). That's neat. Also, I'm glad you brought up the consideration about whether sequence matters more than the presence of all the same values.