# How to select multiple fields from a DataView and apply .Distinct() using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to select some fields from `DataView` and after selecting those fields want to apply .Distinct() on these set of fields.

Right now, I used this code :

```
DataView dvGroups = new DataView();
dvGroups = GetDataFromDatabase(); //-- Fill Dataview
var groups = dvGroups.Table.AsEnumerable()
                           .Where(x => x.Field<int>("GroupId") != 0)
                           .Select(p => p.Field<int>("GroupId"))
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToArray();
```

it's only selecting a single field (i.e `"GroupId"`). But, Now i want to select multiple fields (like `"GroupId", "GroupName"`) and then get the distinct value.

How can i achieve this task?

Comment: @Dovnvoter: Can you please, tell me the reason to down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create anonymous objects:

```
.Select(p => new {
    GroupId = p.Field<int>("GroupId"),
    Something = p.Field<string>("Something"),
})
.Distinct().ToArray();
```

for example, because anonymous types are "compatible" with `Distinct()` (see [LINQ Select Distinct with Anonymous Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543482/linq-select-distinct-with-anonymous-types)), because the compiler generates the `Equals`/`GetHashCode` methods.

Or you could use the [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
.Select(p => Tuple.Create(p.Field<int>("GroupId"), p.Field<string>("Something")))
```

But they are normally less clear.

More complex is to create your class and implement the `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an *anonymous* type:

```
var groups = dvGroups.Table
          .AsEnumerable()
          .Where(x => x.Field<int>("GroupId") != 0)
           .Select(p => new 
                        { 
                            id = p.Field<int> ("GroupId"),
                            name = p.Field<string> ("Name"))
                        }).Distinct().ToArray();
```